# Will this mounting plate work when it’s higher than the electrical box?

Tags: light-fixture, outdoor

I’m trying to install a new outdoor light. The old one they had cut the actual sides of the fixture to for it to fit flush on the siding. When I got a mounting block to try, in order for it to be flush with the siding, it is about 2 inches higher than the electrical box. Will this still work?

[image]

I also have this mounting block kit but the box is exposed on the bottom when it is slid up flush against the siding. [image]

Comment: Nah, neither fit. Because you have the hole in the center of a panel, you need a mount which spans three panels such as this one: https://www.amazon.com/Arlington-8141DBL-Siding-Mounting-Built/dp/B0069KVZZ4/ref=mp_s_a_1_3?keywords=outdoor+light+mounting+block&qid=1650586165&sr=8-3#immersive-view_1650586182739

Comment: When it spans 3, it will center in the middle where your outlet is

Comment: @Chris -- make that into an answer and I'll give it a +1

Answer (score 3):

No unfortunately not. Your mounts are designed to mount a hole which sits between two panels.

Because your hole is in the center of a panel, you need a mount which spans three panels such as this one: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0069KVZZ4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069KVZZ4)

[image: Image of box showing installation & dimensions]

Comment: Dude, I've never seen one of those, that's awesome! Also, I embedded a pic in case the link dies (because nobody ever reorganizes a web site...). My wife would be appalled a the color mismatch, but that's a different story...